# SpriteKitで描いたNodeの色を任意で変更したい。

Tags: swift

当方、初心者です。
SpriteKitで描いたNode(図形など）の色を、UISegmentedControl（button)などを使って、任意に変更することは可能でしょうか？
一度Viewに緑色で表示した後、色を変更できるようにしたいと思っています。
緑、黄、赤の三色のうちから任意の色を選べるように設定したいです。
ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SKSpriteNode`限定で説明します。
`SKSpriteNode`の色を、プロパティ`color`で変更することができます。が、その前に、プロパティ`colorBlendFactor`を、デフォルトの`0.0`から最大値`1.0`までの値に変更しておきます。

```
nodeA.colorBlendFactor = 0.5
nodeA.color = UIColor.redColor()
```

`colorBlendFactor`の値が大きいと、比例して`color`の影響が大きくなります。デフォルトでは`0.0`なので、`color`を変更しても、ノードの色に変化が見られません。なので、このプロパティは関係ないのかと、早とちりする人が出てくるかもしれません。`colorBlendFactor`と`color`の組み合わせで、適切な色調整をしてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

`SKSpriteNode`以外のノードについては、それぞれのクラスリファレンスを読んでください。

Comment: Harawo様、アドバイスありがとうございます。SKShapeNodeでの方法も、ご存知でしたら教えていただけますか？できればコード付きで。お願いします。

Comment: @woodpecker 「クラスリファレンスを読んでください」と回答に書いてますね？SKShapeNodeのクラスリファレンスをお読みになりましたか？

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/を見ましたが、私の英語力では理解できませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

遅レスなので、とっくに解決済みと思いますが、他の方のためにも念のため。

```
//円を表示
myShapeNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
myShapeNode?.fillColor = SKColor.red
self.addChild(myShapeNode!)
```

色を変える場合は、以下のようです。

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    //円の色を変える
    myShapeNode?.fillColor = SKColor.blue
}
```